# HTML Text Input with hyperlink/Insert Link feature

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using angularjs for my project and I would like to create a text input with a feature that allow to highlight some part of the text and insert link (hyperlink) just like the the rich text editor

I know about a rich text editor which is text angular but all I need for my project is to insert hyperlink to some text without showing the HTML tag to the user

Right now I am using a regular textarea without any html feature

```
     <textarea
           ng-model="ctrl.sms_instance_template.body"
           ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }"
           class="form-control recipe-input"
           ng-class="{'input-error':ctrl.errors.conversation}"
           ng-change="ctrl.smsMessageTypeChange(ctrl.sms_instance_template)"
                    placeholder="Please enter an introductory message..."
                    required>
      </textarea>
```

Below is the design that I intend to create. Does anyone have any idea ?

[image: an]

Comment: Please provide some code of what you currently have so people know how content is being saved.

Comment: @learningtoanimate I am sorry. I will edit my post

Comment: Could you add a link input that then places the user's URL within the correct tags but links the text like `<a href="[USER-UNPUT]">[URL-TITLE]</a>`?